# Determine if User is in Active Directory Group

Tags: asp.net, iis

I'm using the following code to determine if the user is in a specific group. The code works fine on my local development environment, but when I push it to our development server, it returns false all the time.

Is there something that I need to configure in IIS?

Note: This code is only being run on specific pages. It is not used globally for all web pages.

```
Public Function IsInGroup(ByVal GroupName As String)
    Dim MyIdentity As System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()
    Dim MyPrincipal As System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal = New System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal(MyIdentity)

    '' Web team needs access to all pages. See web.config for value.
    If MyPrincipal.IsInRole(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ISSupportAllAccessADGRoup").ToString.ToUpper) Then
        Return True
    Else
        If MyPrincipal.IsInRole(GroupName) Then
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: is the IIS server set for windows authentication?

Comment: Yes. Windows Authentication is enabled.

Comment: Doing some debugging... On local dev box, Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name  contains the value "ABC\john.doe". On development site, Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name contains the value "NT AUTHORITY\IUSR".

Comment: Another thing I noticed... Anonymous Authentication was set to enabled, I disabled it. When reloading the site, I was asked for credentials. Provided them and now Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name contains the value "ABC\john.doe". However, I need to have Anonymous access available for everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the following page: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.logonuseridentity.aspx

Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name exposes Windows.Princpal. In any case this requires that either 
1) Windows Authentication is enabled
2) Forms authentication is enabled and valid domain credentials are passed to the application in that case.

Otherwise with anonymous access defeats the purpose and will allow anyone in with NO IDENTITY rendering your code meaningless. If there is a subset of functions that you need to identify users for consider setting up a virtual directory /admin for example that can have it's own web.config with windows authentication enabled. For IIS (on the server) IUSR is the default IIS account used when nothing else is available and I am gessing that ABC\John Doe is your account on your workstation. I would further say that the IIS instance that you are running locally is not set to anonymous.

Comment: I've come up with a differernt way to obtain the user's id. Is there a way to pass it to the principal? Example: Dim MyPrincipal As System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal = New System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal("ABC\john.doe")

Comment: the constructor to windpwsPrincipal requires a WindowsIdentity object. (which would still require that the target be a valid windows domain\user pair and admin access. I am recommending against this. you can implement your own security lookup and avoid the use of windows.principal however (usernames/hashed passwords stored in a database for example.